# Parameters to calculate affluence in localities of Metro city

Tags: datasets, data-science

I have to calculate the affluence in localities of Metro city. To calculate affluence, I am considering a parameter per capita income.

Where I can get a dataset of it? What are other parameters I should consider for the problem?

Any guidance will be fruitful for me.

Comment: This is not really an AI question...

Comment: I think collecting data is an important part of AI. "Data is new Oil" Andrew Ng

Comment: Should be re-opened based on the fact that a general conceptual answer might be given on how parameters of a given problem is determined without redundancy, OR this should be migrated to DataScience.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affluence could encompass several parameters:
Income;
Wealth (property ownership);
Life expectancy;
Access to services such as education and health;
Access to clean natural resources;
Low levels of criminality.

Property prices in each locality might be easy to obtain from real estate agent sources
Ratings for schools or medical facilities in each area might be published

Generally, where public statistics are collected on a locality, they will be related in one way or another to affluence. A useful strategy might be to collect as many of these diverse data sets as possible, and to learn a composite affluence score from the data. It is very likely that all of these parameters will be correlated to a greater or lesser degree, and so you could accurately learn about affluence from a small number of these parameters.